# Possible bug in JIT or CLR

Tags: c#, .net, clr, jit, reflection.emit

My code generates a method to dynamically create a multidimensional array assuming an array of dimension lengths, however it seems the the JIT-compiler or even the CLR fails to load items from the dimension lengths array appropriately.

Instead of creating an array of `int[10, 10, 10]`, an array of `int[10, 10, 0]` is created. It appears to go wrong at `OpCodes.Ldelem_I`, however, using `OpCodes.Ldelem, typeof(int)` instead just works. The reproduce this behavior, Any CPU settings are required, x86 works fine. This problem occurs on both debug and release mode.

So is this a bug? I feel to uncertain to judge this as I am unable to dig deeper into this.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateMultidimensionalArrayCreator(typeof(int[, ,])).Invoke(new int[] { 10, 10, 10 }); ;            
    }

    static Func<int[], Array> CreateMultidimensionalArrayCreator(Type type)
    {
        int rank = type.GetArrayRank();

        DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod(String.Empty, typeof(Array), new Type[] { typeof(int[]) }, typeof(Program), false);
        ILGenerator ilGen = method.GetILGenerator();

        for (int i = 0; i < rank; i++)
        {
            // Load element from dimension lengths array
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, i);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_I); // Somehow returns 0 for last element, however, OpCodes.Ldelem appears to work fine
            // Duplicate element and write to console for diagnostics
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(int) }));
        }

        // Get parameters for multidimensional array constructor
        //
        Type[] parameterTypes = new Type[rank];

        for (int i = 0; i < rank; i++)
        {
            parameterTypes[i] = typeof(int);
        }

        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, type.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, parameterTypes, null));
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return (Func<int[], Array>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int[], Array>));
    }
}
```

Comment: This program outputs some numbers, can you tell us what you observed and what you expected, instead of leaving this as implied by your text?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - [Here](http://oi58.tinypic.com/33aykg8.jpg) is a tangible screenshot.

Comment: I also get 10,10,10 on VS2015

Comment: @leppie AnyCPU? Which .NET version?

Comment: AnyCPU / x64 with Visual Studio 2013, .NET Framework 4, reproduces this problem.

Comment: Targetting CLR 2 also produces the error. Maybe RyuJIT fixed the issue?

Comment: Funny, now it fails every time, first time it did not...

Comment: Fwiw, my settings are `x64 / Visual Studio 2010 / AnyCPU`. Framework version and build config doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: Why are you using `Ldelem_I` in the first place?

Comment: It seems to fail as soon as you change the project target. Changing it back does not fix it.

Comment: @leppe - Because the elements of the array are always native ints.

Comment: You do realize a 'native int` is a pointer? You should use `Ldelem_I4` for `Int32`.

Comment: @leppie - I just switched to x86, problem gone, switched back to Any CPU and still no problem. This is very odd.

Comment: @leppie - No I didn't realize, I should use Ldelem_I4 eitherway, indeed.

Comment: No it is not odd, `native int` on 64bit is basically a `Int64`. BTW, everything works fine when using `Ldelem_I4`. I suggest you dump the IL to an assembly and run PEVerify on it. It error out on a type issue.

Comment: When changing the element values and using a 4-element array I observe that it uses the 0th, 2nd, 4th, and 6th elements, not 0th, 1st, and 2nd.

Comment: The documentation says that it uses the index though, and it also specifically says that integer values less than 4 bytes in size is expanded to int32, odd that it handles such arrays and not int arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Replace line:

```
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_I); // Somehow returns...
```

to line:

```
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_I4); // Somehow returns 0 for last element....
```